# laravel 8 use orderBy and withMax for order tables with another table

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

i want to orderby products with max price from details table.

products one to many relation with details table.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel documentation we have aggregate methods like `withMax` ,`withMin` and `withCount`
. These methods will place a `{relation}_{function}_{column}` attribute on your resulting models.
now we only need to orderBy with this results.

```
            $products = Product::withMax('details', 'price')
            ->orderBy('details_max_price' , 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);
```